# не работает tcp связь вне локальной сети

Tags: c++, сеть, tcp, sfml

```
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

static bool port_is_open(const std::string& address, int port)
{
return (sf::TcpSocket().connect(address, port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}

int main()
{
    string machine;
string serverIp = "93.171.161.201";
if (serverIp == IpAddress::getPublicAddress())
    machine = "server";
else machine = "client";

if (machine == "client")
{
    Packet packet;
    cout << "Ya client" << endl;
    TcpSocket socket;
    if (socket.connect(serverIp, 5007) == Socket::Done)
        cout << "You are connected now" << endl;
    else cout << "none" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        if(socket.receive(packet) == Socket::Done)
        {
            Vector2i coords;
            packet >> coords.x >> coords.y;
            Mouse::setPosition(coords);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Ya server" << endl;
    TcpListener listener;
    listener.listen(5007);
    TcpSocket client;
    if (listener.accept(client) == Socket::Done)
        cout << "All Done" << endl;
    Packet packet;
    while (true)
    {
        packet.clear();
        packet << Mouse::getPosition().x << Mouse::getPosition().y;
        client.send(packet);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Компьютер находится за NAT
Коннект работает только в локальной сети. Вот мой проброс порта :
[image: port forwarding]

До сих пор не работает. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: А telnet работает на этот хост/порт?
`telnet <ip> <port>`

Comment: при вводе этой команды пишет, что невозможно установить подключение к узлу. Возможно я использую не тот ip. Использую для подключения внешний ip сети.

Comment: Я у вас вижу локальный адрес 192.168.0.1, для соединения такой адрес не годится. Первое - должен работать пинг либо на крайний случай - telnet по вашему порту. Если это не работает - то проблема настроек сети.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, при чем тут мой локальный ip. Я его не использую. У меня есть 2 компьютера. Они находятся в разных сетях. Один я использую в качестве сервера, другой является клиентом. Насколько я понял, для того, чтобы происходил конект, нужно сделать port forwarding, так как роутер не пускает никаких конектов из вне, соответственно невозможно подключение. Вот полностью моя ситуация. Адрес 192.168.0.1 я нигде не использую. Лишь мой локальный адрес 192.168.0.101, на который и происходит port forwarding, обходя защиту роутера

Comment: Это явно проблемы настройки сети. Картинка не даёт информации от слова *совсем*.

Comment: А какие варианты могут быть ? Я пытался исправить проблемы с брандмауэром винды, думал не проходит запрос, может знаете варианты обнаружения конкретных проблем ?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно (так как сервер и клиент находятся в разных сетях) , ваш провайдер использует "серый" ip для подключения вас к всемирной сети (то есть на 1 публичный ip приходится несколько серых) и если для подключения ваших устройств используются разные публичные ip адреса , то устройства не смогут подключиться друг к другу.